# pg_dump only dumps table info, and very little table data?

Tags: postgresql

```
pg_dump -U postgres mydb > mydb.bak.sql
```

From the docs, it doesn't seem like I need to pass any flag to include table data in a dump. Yet, the dump resulting from the above includes data for a strange, tiny subset of tables--aside from their create statements, most tables are only listed as

```
COPY <tablename> (vals) FROM stdin;
\.
```

Is there some circumstance where you have to explicitly tell pg_dump to include all table data?

Comment: are you sure you are using correct schema ? `pg_dump -U postgres -d dbName -n "\"SCHEMA_NAME\"" > schema.dump`

Comment: Are you sure that you dumping correct database/postgres instance/host? Does pg_dump produce any messages? If you connect with same connection parameters via psql - are you able to see missed data?

Comment: No, you don't have to tell pg_dump to include all tables. This is the default behaviour

Comment: I forgot the -d flag before the database name. I'm used to mysql which assumes the database name. pg_dump didn't throw up any error without the d flag, though, so I assumed it dumped correctly.